# call controller method from a view file with MVC pattern in PHP

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm writing a simple PHP website with MVC pattern (I'm not using any framework because for this website I don't want to use them).
Now I'm stuck on calling a method inside a controller from a view.

I want to create a login form, this is what I have:
**My view**

```
<?php

    include_once("controller/ControllerRegLog.php");
    $mycontroller = new ControllerRegLog();
?>  
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">    
</head>

<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="container">
    <form id='register' action='????????' method='post'>
    <fieldset >
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
    <input type='text' name='username' id='username' />

    <label for='password' >Password:</label>
    <input type='password' name='password' id='password' />
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />

    </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my **controller** (ControllerRegLog.php)

```
<?php
include_once("model/Model.php");

class ControllerRegLog {
    public $model;

    public function __construct()  
    {  
        $this->model = new Model();

    } 
    public function logincheck()
    {
        $loginresponse = $this->model->checkLogin();        
    }

?>
```

And finally my **model**:

```
<?php

class Model 
{
    public function checkLogin()
    {
         // here should go a database call to see if credentials for login are valid
    }   
}

?>
```

Look at the view. I don't know what sould be written inside the action="..." in order to pass the form values to controller for checking the credentials.

I tried with bad result (page not found) with `ControllerRegLog/loginCheck` and `<?php echo $mycontroller."/loginCheck" ?>`

Comment: I don't believe there is enough information here to properly answer your question. How are requests are being routed? Perhaps that will explain why you're getting a 404.

Comment: Since you are not using a Framework, you'll have to recreate the routing logic yourself as well. Because you are calling `ControllerRegLog/loginCheck` without telling your scripts what that means. (That's the advantage of using a Framework - those tasks are taken care of for you :)

Comment: It is admirable you are creating your own MVC but I think you should check at least how a framework works. For instance the controller should decide what view is rendered, the controller sends variables to the template etc...

Comment: (another example) You could use a htaccess to specify which controller(in a routing class), based on the accessed url, to instantiate a certain class and which method to call (or displaying a 404 error page).